# I have a simple code how to simplify this code to make it simpler

Tags: vb.net

```
 Sub voicecounterA()


    If counterA = 1 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SCOM1, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    ElseIf counterA = 2 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SCOM2, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    ElseIf counterA = 3 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SCOM3, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    ElseIf counterA = 4 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SCOM4, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    ElseIf counterA = 5 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SCOM5, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    ElseIf counterA = 6 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SCOM6, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    ElseIf counterA = 7 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SCOM7, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    ElseIf counterA = 8 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SCOM8, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    ElseIf counterA = 9 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SCOM9, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    ElseIf counterA = 10 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SCOM10, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    ElseIf counterA = 101 Then
        My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.SCOM10, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)


    End If
End Sub
```

[I have a simple code how to simplify this code to make it simpler, so when I click on Call menu it will be call next voice, so I dont have to use so many code if i want to call 100 people](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65bnT.jpg)

I am using vb

Comment: Is this VBA, VB.NET **or** VbScript?

Comment: VBA? vbScript? VB.Net? Vb6?

Comment: In what way you want to simplify this more? Personally i would use a `Select Case` but that does not reduce the amount of code needed. Imo this is simple and clear enough

Comment: I am using VB.NET

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `Dictionary(Of Int32, String)`, then your code becomes:

```
Private Shared AudioResources As New Dictionary(Of Int32, String) From 
    {{1, My.Resources.SCOM1},{2, My.Resources.SCOM2},{3, My.Resources.SCOM3},{4, My.Resources.SCOM4},{5, My.Resources.SCOM5},
     {6, My.Resources.SCOM6},{7, My.Resources.SCOM7},{8, My.Resources.SCOM8},{9, My.Resources.SCOM9},{10, My.Resources.SCOM10},{101, My.Resources.SCOM10}}


Sub voicecounterA()
    Dim audioResource As String = Nothing
    If AudioResources.TryGetValue(counterA, audioResource)
         My.Computer.Audio.Play(audioResource, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou for answering my question #Schmelter, I was trying to use this code but still not work